# RNFetchBlob.android.actionViewIntent does not working on android 11

Tags: android, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

I have updated my Android's **targetSdkVersion** to **30**, and I realized that the **actionViewIntent** function does not work on Android 11.

There is no error thrown. So I can't able to debug.

Below is my code:

```
RNFetchBlob.android.actionViewIntent(filePath, mimeType);
```

Has anyone else had this issue after updating? Please assist me!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to solve it? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Yeah! Please see my solution for how I solved it!

Comment: Is this solution still working for you? It was working for me at one point but now on Android 11 only, doing this RNFetchBlob.android.actionViewIntent(filePath, mimeType)  doesn't open the PDF anymore.  Still works on Android 10 or 12 though. Very puzzling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding ["queries"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element) in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>

<application ....
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this, I solved it too.